# Error while adding firebaseui dependency

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to use FirebaseListAdapter and for it , it requires 
dependency of com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0 . But when I add this in my gradle file I am getting an error in

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
```

below are the screenshot and code for app.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashish.internchat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
}







apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using mismatching library versions. `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable` is version `25.3.1` while your `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7` is version `25.1.1`. Using mismatched versions could cause your app to crash/errors. FirebaseUi must be using version `25.1.1`.

Add the below to your apps gradle:

`compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'`